# Flex 4: How to apply RectangularDropShadow?

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to `Flex` so there are things that I am not used to. I have added the `RectangularDropShadow` in the `Declarations` tag of a `Rect` MXML component. It does not show anything, I am sure there is something more I should do to apply it to the `Rect`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Rect xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        height="314" width="478">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:RectangularDropShadow id="cardAreaShadow"                                
                                 alpha="0.4"
                                 distance="10"
                                 angle="45"
                                 color="#000000" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Declarations` block is meant only for declaring objects. So what you're doing here, is creating an instance of `RectangularDropShadow` without adding it to the displaylist, which is of course why you can't see it.

Another thing to know is that `RectangularDropShadow` is a bit of an odd one: it's not a filter, but a DisplayObject in its own right. For clarity: filters are "visual effects" that can be applied to existing DisplayObjects. Whereas `RectangularDropShadow` is in fact just a rectangular shape with some gradients applied to it.

Also, because it's a DisplayObject and `Rect` is not a container, you can't simply remove the `Declarations` tag and expect it to work. You have to put the two objects on top of each other, like this:

```
<s:RectangularDropShadow id="cardAreaShadow" height="314" width="478"
                         alpha="0.4" distance="10" angle="45" color="#000000" />

<s:Rect height="314" width="478">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

An alternative is to simply apply a `DropShadowFilter` to the `Rect` instead of using the `RectangularDropShadow`:

```
<s:Rect height="314" width="478">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#FFFFFF" />
    </s:fill>
    <s:filters>
        <s:DropShadowFilter alpha="0.4" distance="10" angle="45" color="#000000" />
    </s:filters>
</s:Rect>
```

**If we have filters, then why do we need `RectangularDropShadow`?**
The reason is performance: a simple shape with a simple gradient can be calculated for more effectively than a filter applied to an arbitrary existing DisplayObject.

Comment: what I want to achieve is to have a shadow all around the `Rect`.

Comment: Both techniques should work for that. The RectangularDropShadow can be positioned whereever you want below the Rect. As for the filter: if you want the shadow to be evenly distributed around all the edges, better use GlowFilter instead (or set the `distance` to 0 and apply a high blur to the DropShadowFilter)